# error:NumberFormatException unable to parse '20'

Tags: java, android

```
public void onPass(View v)
    {

        String sn1=et1.getText().toString();
        String sn2=et2.getText().toString();

        int i1=Integer.parseInt(sn1);
        int i2=Integer.parseInt(sn2);
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Act2.class);
        i.putExtra("k1",i1 );
        i.putExtra("k2", i2);       
        startActivity(i);       

    }
```

**logcat** :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(671): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '20 ' as integer
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a white space at the end of the String. That's the problem. You'll need to trim it.

Comment: after doing that there's a new error as in logcat 05-14 14:51:34.018: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4d2

Answer (score 4):

You have a white space at the end of your input. Try :

```
String sn1=et1.getText().toString().trim();
String sn2=et2.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: after doing that there's a new error as in logcat 05-14 14:51:34.018: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4d2

Answer (score 1):

```
'20 ' // <<---- you have a whitespace at the end
```

You need to [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) it before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to trim the string because you have a white space at the end you can do this:

```
int i1=Integer.parseInt(sn1.trim());
int i2=Integer.parseInt(sn2.trim());
```

or :

you can change like zouzou said :

```
String sn1=et1.getText().toString().trim();
String sn2=et2.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: after doing that there's a new error as in logcat 05-14 14:51:34.018: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4d2

Comment: so maybe "sn1" or "sn2" ar already integer or is not String
try this:
    int i1=Integer.parseInt(sn1.toString().trim());
    int i2=Integer.parseInt(sn2.toString().trim());

hope it will work :)
(Or int i1=Integer.parseInt((sn1+"").trim()); ... )